# ag-dired can't find any file

Tags: microsoft-windows

Searching for `helm.el` with [`ag.el`](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el) in the Helm directory produces this error:

```bash
d:/emacs/share/emacs/site-lisp/helm/helm-1.7.0/:
  ag --nocolor -g 'helm\.el' "d:/emacs/share/emacs/site-lisp/helm/helm-1.7.0/" | grep -v '^$' | sed s/\'/\\\\\'/ | xargs -I '{}' ls -alh '{}' &
  sed: -e expression #1,        char 8: unterminated `s' command

  ag finished at Tue Apr 28 16:16:58
```

I am using MSYS on Windows 7 32 bit

Comment: This is nothing to do with Emacs.  The problem, as stated in the error message you receive, is something to do with the `sed` expression.

Comment: @rekado No, this is actually caused by a bug in the Emacs package `ag.el` (see [this line](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el/blob/9f0c3a70035d48738569d1095f53686e772c1dd2/ag.el#L469) and [this issue](https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el/issues/87)).

Comment: This was not clear from the original question.  Anyway, in my opinion StackExchange should not be used for bug reports.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in ag.el, see: https://github.com/Wilfred/ag.el/issues/87

(I initially misunderstood the question.  Please consider updating it for clarity.)

Comment: This is incorrect; see my comment on the OP.

Comment: @PythonNut Thanks. I have revoked my close vote.